# How to get xy coordinate but not starts from window browser, instead starts from div?

Tags: jquery

Aloha all!!

I have a problem here...Im using jquery here..n using visual studio 2008..I need to find the coordinate of an image after being drag n drop in a div.But what I had got is that the coordinate counts from out of div..I want it counts from inside the div..

Please...anyone??

Here's my code:

```
    $('#dragThis').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#dragThis2',
    drag: function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
    var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

    // Show dropped position.
    var Startpos = $("#dragThis").position();
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();

    $("#dragThis2").val((Stoppos.left - Startpos.left));
    var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
    var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
    $('#posX').text('left: ' + left);
    $('#posY').text('top: ' + top);
    }

   });
```

Comment: you can always subtract the offset of div from image position to relative offset

Comment: ok,can u give me sample code on how to subtract?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent.

```
var pos = $(this).position();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jquerypp.com/#within.
This function does exact the task.

Answer (score 0):

If `#dragThis2` is your parent div then

```
var parentLeft = $("#dragThis2").position().left;
var parentTop = $("#dragThis2").position().top;

var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left - parentLeft);
var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top - parentTop);
$('#posX').text('left: ' + left);
$('#posY').text('top: ' + top);​
```

will give you `left` and `top` relative to parent div `#dragThis2`